# I cant launch wine application from terminal

Tags: 16.04, wine

When I tried open windows program using wine, i get strange output

```
0030:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0030:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0030:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0030:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0030:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0030:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0030:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0030:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0030:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0030:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0030:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0030:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0030:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0030:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0030:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0030:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0030:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0030:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0030:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0030:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0030:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0030:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0030:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0030:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0030:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
```

the app launched but it's closed immediately after. How to solve?

Answer (score 0):

The problem seem to goes away after I install latest version of wine, app launched normally without eror this time